# Task switch (alt-tab) not working properly when in full screen

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, fullscreen, application-switcher

I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04 with the classic environment. Whenever I am in the full-screen mode (evince, chrome, firefox, vlc etc.) and trying switch the task to some other running process, it is not working. Means, I am remaining in the existing 'full-screen' window; to properly switch, I needed to exit from the full-screen. It is working as intended in Compiz and Mate environment but the problem is consistent in the gnome-classic.